# Problems while sending/receiving data via sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ncurses

I'm working on a simple chat program with ncurses UI in C, and have encountered this strange issue.

**It goes as follows:**

1. Server waits for clients to connect.
2. When a client is connected, server prompts for username.
3. After receiving the username, server starts listening for messages from client.
4. Each time server receives a message, it concatenates it with the username, and broadcasts it to all the clients, so the message clients are receiving should look like this:

```
username: text
```

Here is where something goes wrong.

**Client output:**

```
test^U^D: hello waddup
```

So, basically, first six indexes of received array are always filled with these escape characters, which are printed on the client side, if username is shorter than 6 letters.

Like this:

```
USERNAME: a //user input                             
YOU: test message                                    a^C^\^?^U^D: test message
```

While investigating this problem, I've added debug messages on server side.

**Server output:**

```
USERNAME RECEIVED:
: message
//tested one-letter username - q
USERNAME RECEIVED: q
q: asd
//two-letter - qw
USERNAME RECEIVED: as
as: sdf
//three-letter - asd. Still doesn't print the last letter, eventhough on client side it is printed, probably some stupid mistake I've made and didn't notice yet
USERNAME RECEIVED: test
test: hello
//Finally prints full u-name. No escape characters like on client side.
//If u-name >= 4 let. it is displayed normally on server side. If uname >= 6 -- on client side
```

My guess is that problem appears on the socket layer, but I'm not 
knowledgeable enough in socket programming to be confident in my suggestions.

Alternatively, the problem may be linked to ncurses UI, since it is visible on client side (which uses ncurses), and isn't visible on server side (which prints debug messages to sdout).

I know it probably is really messy and inefficient, but this project is my first relatively serious C project, and I surely will refactor and optimize this code later.

Code of problematic function on server side:

```c
void transmitt(int socket, int index){
        printf("CONNECTION TO THREAD %x\n", pthread_self());
        char tmp[MAX];
        char bye[MAX];
        char uname[MAX_UNAME];
        char buffer[MAX+MAX_UNAME];
        sprintf(bye, "%d", BYE_MESSAGE);
        recv_uname(socket, uname);
        while(1){
                bzero(tmp, sizeof(tmp));
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                recv(socket, tmp, sizeof(tmp), 0);
                if(strncmp(bye, tmp, MAX) == 0){
                        printf("THREAD: %x DISCONNECTED\n", pthread_self());
                        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "SERVER MESSAGE: %s HAS DISCONNECTED", uname);
                        for(int i =0;i<MAX_CLIENTS;i++){
                                if(clients[i] != NULL){
                                        send(clients[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                                }
                        }
                        clients[index] = NULL;
                        return;
                }
                snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s: %s", uname, tmp);
                for(int i =0;i<MAX_CLIENTS;i++){
                        if(clients[i] != NULL){
                                send(clients[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                        }
                }
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
}

void recv_uname(int socket, char* uname){
        char prompt[MAX_UNAME];
        snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), "USERNAME: ");
        send(socket, prompt, sizeof(prompt), 0);
        recv(socket, uname, MAX_UNAME, 0);
        printf("USERNAME RECEIVED: %s\n", uname);
}
```

Client side:

```c
void chat_loop(int socket){
        char buff[MAX], sbuff[MAX+MAX_UNAME];
        char tmp;
        int n, y=0, x=0, maxcol, maxrow, recy, recx;
        getmaxyx(stdscr, maxrow, maxcol);
        recy = 0;
        recx = maxcol/2;
        timeout(1);
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        printw("YOU: ");
        n=0;
        while(1){
                tmp = getch();
                getyx(stdscr, y, x);
                if(tmp == '`'){
                        sprintf(buff, "%d", BYE_MESSAGE);
                        send(socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
                        return;
                }
                else if(tmp == '\n'){
                        send(socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
                        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        //              printw("YOU: ");
                        move(++y, 0);
                        n=0;
                }
                else if(tmp == ALT_BACKSPACE){
                        if(x > 0){
                                mvdelch(y, x-1);
                                buff[--n] = NULL;
                        }
                }
                else if(tmp != ERR){
                        printw("%c", tmp);
                        buff[n++] = tmp;
                }

                bzero(sbuff, sizeof(sbuff));
                recv(socket, sbuff, sizeof(sbuff), MSG_DONTWAIT);
                if(check_buff(sbuff, sizeof(sbuff)) == 0){
                        getyx(stdscr, y, x);
                        move(recy++, recx);
                        printw("%s", sbuff);
                        move(y, x);
                }
                refresh();
        }
}

void send_uname(int socket){
        char buff[MAX], unbuff[MAX_UNAME];
        char tmp;
        int n=0, y=0, x=0, init_x;
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        recv(socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        printw("%s", buff);
        getyx(stdscr, y, init_x);
        while((tmp = getch())!='\n'){
                getyx(stdscr, y, x);
                if(tmp == ALT_BACKSPACE){
                        if(x > init_x){
                                mvdelch(y, x-1);
                                unbuff[--n] = NULL;
                        }
                }
                else if(tmp != ERR){
                        if(n < MAX_UNAME){
                                printw("%c", tmp);
                                unbuff[n++] = tmp;
                        }
                }
                refresh();
        }
        printw("\n");
        send(socket, unbuff, sizeof(unbuff), 0);
}

int check_buff(char* buffer, size_t n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(buffer[i]!=NULL)
                        return 0;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Constants and includes:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<ncurses.h>

//common
#define ALT_BACKSPACE 127
#define MAX 128 //common buffer size
#define MAX_UNAME 24
#define BYE_MESSAGE 10101010

//server-specific
#define MAX_THREADS 4
#define MAX_CLIENTS 4
```

[GitHub link with full code](https://github.com/Jokey82/chad-chat)

That is all I've got.

Comment: This is not a problem with sockets, but with your strings that is not null terminated

Comment: This code contains the same mistake everybody makes when using TCP for the first time — it assumes that recv() will write a certain number of bytes into the local array, and doesn’t check recv’s return value to see how many bytes it *actually* wrote.  Reality is that recv() may write any number of bytes between 1 and (the value you specified in your size argument), and its up to you to do the right thing regardless of how many bytes you received on any given call.

Comment: I've tested this application on another machine and it worked normally. Anyway,  thanks for your answers. Importance of checking recv() return value is something I wasn't aware of before.

Comment: @AndrewWilbik just because the code "works" on one machine does not mean the code is *correct*.

Comment: Design/write your code so that it will work correctly if every call to read/recv returns an negative error, zero, (stream closed),  or one, (ie one byte only loaded into the buffer).  Assuming anything else is wrong, and it WILL bite you eventually:(